# Python: Split a mixed String

Tags: python

I read some lines from a file in the following form:

```
line = a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n
```

What I want is lines without the ","-separated elements, e.g.,

```
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n 
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n
.   .  .  .    .   .  .   .   .
.   .  .  .    .   .  .   .   .
```

First I would split `line`

```
sline = line.split()
```

Now I would iterate over `sline` and look for elements that can be  splited with "," as separator. The Problem is I don't know always how much from those elements I have to expect.
Any ideas?

Comment: So, you want to remove a comma and an element after it? How long(in characters) could it be? Could be a space between the comma and the element?

Comment: It  loks like You need to repeat Your line for each of items separated by `,`. Am I correct?

Comment: @Tengis: could you clarify your question please?  Your text suggests that you just want to *remove* any part of a field after a comma.  But your example seems to show that you want to *expand* any comma-separated field into multiple lines.  So which is it, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `regex`, `itertools.product` and some string formatting:

This solution preserves the initial spacing as well.

```
>>> import re
>>> from itertools import product
>>> line = 'a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n'
>>> items = [x[0].split(',') for x in re.findall(r'((\w+,)+\w)',line)]
>>> strs = re.sub(r'((\w+,)+\w+)','{}',line)
>>> for prod in product(*items):
...     print (strs.format(*prod))
...     
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  l   m   n
```

Another example:

```
>>> line = 'a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n q,w,e,r  f o   o'
>>> items = [x[0].split(',') for x in re.findall(r'((\w+,)+\w)',line)]
>>> strs = re.sub(r'((\w+,)+\w+)','{}',line)
for prod in product(*items):
    print (strs.format(*prod))
...     
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  i   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  i   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  i   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  i   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  j   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  j   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  j   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  j   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  k   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  k   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  k   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  k   m   n r  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  l   m   n q  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  l   m   n w  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  l   m   n e  f o   o
a   b  c  f    g   h  l   m   n r  f o   o
```

Comment: Better than mine, as it preserves the whitespace between the items.

Comment: Ouch, this might be a bit dangerous, depending on the kind of data.  What if the data contains `{}` somewhere?  If it's really important to keep the original spacing, then I would do it another way.

Comment: @MiniQuark In case if the data contains `{}` somewhere, we can escape them first using `{{}}`.

Comment: I guess you're right, but it's error-prone. Honestly, I prefer my answer.  :-)  I edited it to allow keeping the original spacing.

Comment: I'm sorry, my statement was a bit blunt.  I just meant that your code will not work with every possible line: for example, if you run your code with `line = 'a{}   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n'` then you will get an `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.  In general, I consider any string read from a file as unsafe, and I don't treat unsafe strings as format templates, ever.  You could of course escape the string first, then unescape it after formatting, but then your code will be way more complex than it needs to be.  So that's why I prefer my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not really clear.  If you want to **strip off** any part after commas (as your text suggests), then a fairly readable one-liner should do:

```
cleaned_line = " ".join([field.split(",")[0] for field in line.split()])
```

If you want to **expand** lines containing comma-separated fields into multiple lines (as your example suggests), then you should use the `itertools.product` function:

```
import itertools
line = "a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n"
line_fields = [field.split(",") for field in line.split()]
for expanded_line_fields in itertools.product(*line_fields):
    print " ".join(expanded_line_fields)
```

This is the output:

```
a b c d g h i m n
a b c d g h j m n
a b c d g h k m n
a b c d g h l m n
a b c e g h i m n
a b c e g h j m n
a b c e g h k m n
a b c e g h l m n
a b c f g h i m n
a b c f g h j m n
a b c f g h k m n
a b c f g h l m n
```

If it's important to **keep the original spacing**, for some reason, then you can replace `line.split()` by `re.findall("([^ ]*| *)", line)`:

```
import re
import itertools
line = "a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n"
line_fields = [field.split(",") for field in re.findall("([^ ]+| +)", line)]
for expanded_line_fields in itertools.product(*line_fields):
    print "".join(expanded_line_fields)
```

This is the output:

```
a   b  c  d    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  d    g   h  l   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  e    g   h  l   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  i   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  j   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  k   m   n
a   b  c  f    g   h  l   m   n
```

Comment: I think it does not answer to the question (see example).

Comment: @Maxime: I think it does.  `"a b c d,e,f g h" => "a b c d g h"`

Comment: Nope. In the first line you need to print "a b c d g h" and then "a b c e g h" and "a b c f g h".

Comment: Oh boy, I see what you mean.  That's not the way I understood the question, though.  I think you're right, but I'll ask Tengis to clarify.  He should have said something like "expand comma separated fields".

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account both interpretations of the question.

Comment: Updated answer to keep original spacing.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your example correctly You need following

```
import itertools
sss = "a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n  d,e,f "
coma_separated = [i for i in sss.split() if ',' in i]
spited_coma_separated = [i.split(',') for i in coma_separated]
symbols = (i for i in itertools.product(*spited_coma_separated)) 
                     #use generator statement to save memory
for s in symbols:
    st = sss
    for part, symb in zip(coma_separated, s):
        st = st.replace(part, symb, 1) # To prevent replacement of the 
                                       # same coma separated group replace once 
                                       # for first occurance
    print (st.split()) # for python3 compatibility
```

Comment: Seems complicated but it works. Can you make it work for Python3 too?

Answer (score 1):

Most other answers only produce one line instead of the multiple lines you seem to want.

To achieve what you want, you can work in several ways.

The recursive solution seems the most intuitive to me:

```
def dothestuff(l):
    for n, i in enumerate(l):
        if ',' in i:
            # found a "," entry
            items = i.split(',')
            for j in items:
                for rest in dothestuff(l[n+1:]):
                    yield l[:n] + [j] + rest
            return
    yield l


line = "a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n"
for i in dothestuff(line.split()): print i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(line)-1):
    if line[i] == ',':
        line = line.replace(line[i]+line[i+1], '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
line_data = 'a   b  c  d,e,f    g   h  i,j,k,l   m   n'
comma_fields_indices = [i for i,val in enumerate(line_data.split()) if "," in val]
comma_fields = [i.split(",") for i in line_data.split() if "," in i]
all_comb = []
for val in itertools.product(*comma_fields):
    sline_data = line_data.split()
    for index,word in enumerate(val):
        sline_data[comma_fields_indices[index]] = word
    all_comb.append(" ".join(sline_data))
print all_comb
```

Comment: You probably want `" ".join(sline_data)` instead of `",".join(sline_data)`